# How can I get the Current URL Protocol in DNN?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

How can I get Https or Http in the backend code of a DNN module?

Currently, I have got this code, but I need the protocol (**https://** or **http://**)

```
PortalSettings.Current.PortalAlias.HTTPAlias + PortalSettings.HomeDirectory + PortalSettings.LogoFile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe use this to check if the current tab has https enabled (to check the request itself you can use `Request.IsSecureConnection`)

```
PortalSettings.ActiveTab.IsSecure
```

And/or

```
PortalSettings.SSLEnabled;
PortalSettings.SSLEnforced;
PortalSettings.SSLURL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it for the current URL, you can use the regular .NET API's as well.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme
```

That will return http or https based on the current request URL.  Its the fastest way that I'm aware of to do this.